# Hadoop datanode cannot restart after its failure

Tags: hadoop

I am running Map/Reduce tasks with hadoop 1.2.1.

While running heavy MR tasks, I encountered data node failure. The log messages follows:

```
2017-01-24 21:55:41,735 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: java.net.BindException: Problem binding to /0.0.0.0:50020 : 
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.bind(Server.java:267)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Listener.<init>(Server.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.<init>(Server.java:1539)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.<init>(RPC.java:569)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getServer(RPC.java:530)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.startDataNode(DataNode.java:554)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.<init>(DataNode.java:321)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:1712)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:1651)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:1669)                                                                                                                                                         at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:1795)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:1812)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: 
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)                                                                                                                                                                                                          at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server.bind(Server.java:265)
        ... 11 more
```

I guess, after the data node failure, it tried to restart but it failed.

How can I make it able to restart normally? so that the whole MR task is not harmed.

I cannot increase data replication factor in HDFS (it's set to 1 currently) due to the space problem of disks

Comment: Error you are getting when try to restart ??????

Comment: @UserSx I didn't explicitly try to restart. After the failure, the logs are just written in that way. (Data node restarts by itself?)